# What does 'Random State' do? In regards to SMOTE, BSMOTE, & ADASYN (python library: imblearn.over_sampling)

Tags: python, smote

I am confused about how the 'random state' function impacts the operation of SMOTE, BSMOTE, & ADASYN.
Below is the example code from the imblearn page as well as the information about random state for SMOTE.

```
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=2,
weights=[0.1, 0.9], n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, flip_y=0,
print('Original dataset shape %s' % Counter(y))
Original dataset shape Counter({1: 900, 0: 100})
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
X_res, y_res = sm.fit_resample(X, y)
print('Resampled dataset shape %s' % Counter(y_res))
Resampled dataset shape Counter({0: 900, 1: 900})
```

random_state : int, RandomState instance, default=None

Control the randomization of the algorithm.

If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator;

If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator;

If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by np.random

From what I can tell, for all values in ranges 0-42 for random state, it doesn't make a difference to the performance of my classifier. Can someone please give some clarification as to what random state actually does? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The "random_state" parameter in SMOTE, BSMOTE, and ADASYN is used to control the randomness or variability of the algorithms. These algorithms generate synthetic samples by interpolating between the minority class examples in the feature space, and the randomness in this process may affect the quality of the synthetic samples and the overall performance of the classifier. By setting the random_state parameter to a fixed value, you can ensure that the algorithm generates the same synthetic samples each time it is run, which can make the results more reproducible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).